# Airflow telling me "no such file or directory"

Tags: python, linux, bash, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am learning. So forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I am trying to run a DAG but it is failing. This is the code up to the point of failure:

```
        # import the libraries

        from datetime import timedelta
        # The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
        from airflow import DAG
        # Operators; we need this to write tasks!
        from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
        # This makes scheduling easy
        from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

        #defining DAG arguments

        # You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
        default_args = {
            'owner': 'Anthony Guglielmi',
            'start_date': days_ago(0),
            'email': ['anthony@somemail.com'],
            'email_on_failure': True,
            'email_on_retry': True,
            'retries': 1,
            'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
        }

        # defining the DAG

        # define the DAG
        dag = DAG(
            'ETL_toll_data',
            default_args=default_args,
            description='Apache Airflow Final Assignment',
            schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
        )

        # define the tasks

        # define the first task

        unzip_data = BashOperator(
            task_id='unzip_data',
            bash_command='tar -xvzf tolldata.tgz',
            dag=dag,
        )
```

When it fails I get this log:

```
        [2022-04-16 20:39:13,492] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing 
<Task(BashOperator): unzip_data> on 2022-04-16 20:39:10.718322+00:00
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,500] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 973 
to run task
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,508] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['***', 
'tasks', 'run', 'ETL_toll_data', 'unzip_data', 'manual__2022-04-16T20:39:10.718322+00:00', '--job-id', '2', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/finalassignment/ETL_toll_data.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmptzf0s_qj', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpsr4fkibb']
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,509] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 2: Subtask unzip_data
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,630] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: ETL_toll_data.unzip_data manual__2022-04-16T20:39:10.718322+00:00 [running]> on host 5e2785973b3f
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,804] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=anthony@somemail.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Anthony Guglielmi
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=ETL_toll_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=unzip_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-04-16T20:39:10.718322+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-04-16T20:39:10.718322+00:00
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,807] {subprocess.py:62} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,808] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'tar -xvzf tolldata.tgz']
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,833] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,842] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - tar (child): tolldata.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,842] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,843] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - tar: Child returned status 2
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,843] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,844] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
[2022-04-16 20:39:13,885] {taskinstance.py:1703} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

I'm not quite sure why it is not recognizing the file. I have it downloaded in my /home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment folder. I'm sure it's something simple. I am just a novice and really frustrated and can't seem to find any answers online.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you try changing the command to `pwd` to see where this is executing? Alternatively, using an absolute path for tolldata.tgz may help.

Comment: The big piece of information we're missing is "where/how are you running Airflow?" If it's running directly on your machins, a quick fix might be to change that command to `tar -xzvf /home/project/airflow/dags/finalassignment/tolldata.tgz` (i.e. use the absolute path to the file)

Comment: I'm using airflow through the IBM skills network. It's for a class I'm taking from EDX. I am launching it via bash terminal on the web-based platform. I'm starting Airflow through the terminal. Then uploading the py file via a terminal to $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags. Then I trigger the dag on the web UI link they provide once Airflow starts from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Forward the [cwd option](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.2.5/airflow/operators/bash.py#L53) to the `BashOperator` to set the working directory you would like for the command to be executed in. If the option isn't passed, the command is executed in a temporary directory.

The `cwd` option was added in Airflow 2.2

Since you have the archive downloaded in the dags folder, you can write:

```
    unzip_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='unzip_data',
        bash_command='tar -xvzf tolldata.tgz',
        dag=dag,
        cwd=dag.folder
    )
```